# window.onzoom event for tablets/ipad?

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events

Is there an event, similar to `window.onorientationchange` but triggered when *zoom-in* or *zoom-out* gestures were applied please? iPhone/iPad-related solutions are preferred, cross-tablet-platform solutions are warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQuery resize` works on `iOs`. See http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific "zoom" event for multi touch I'm afraid, but you can use `ongesturestart`, `ongesturechange` and `ongestureend` to deal with them. In iOS using `event.preventDefault` method will prevent the zoom.

See:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html